# Elasticsearch stops refreshing

Tags: elasticsearch

in Elasticsearch 6.6.2 i'm having this weird problem
where elastic stops refreshing all indexes. Any UPDATE/INDEX/DELETE operation
returns OK result but search is not showing changes. I see no errors in logs.
If i try to manually force refresh by API this will run forever with no response.
If i restart ES it resumes working correctly and all documents indexed during blackout are there. The problem appears again after few days. This is happening on only one single instance out of many tens that we have in production with exactly the same configuration.
All indexes are open and green.

UPDATE:
this is the output of /someindex/_settings?include_defaults during problem:

```
{
    "someindex": {
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "creation_date": "1627983403578",
                "number_of_shards": "5",
                "number_of_replicas": "1",
                "uuid": "eWWHKAsHQYix3uZSTs6YXg",
                "version": {
                    "created": "6060299"
                },
                "provided_name": "someindex"
            }
        },
        "defaults": {
            "index": {
                "max_inner_result_window": "100",
                "unassigned": {
                    "node_left": {
                        "delayed_timeout": "1m"
                    }
                },
                "max_terms_count": "65536",
                "lifecycle": {
                    "name": "",
                    "rollover_alias": "",
                    "indexing_complete": "false"
                },
                "routing_partition_size": "1",
                "max_docvalue_fields_search": "100",
                "merge": {
                    "scheduler": {
                        "max_thread_count": "2",
                        "auto_throttle": "true",
                        "max_merge_count": "7"
                    },
                    "policy": {
                        "reclaim_deletes_weight": "2.0",
                        "floor_segment": "2mb",
                        "max_merge_at_once_explicit": "30",
                        "max_merge_at_once": "10",
                        "max_merged_segment": "5gb",
                        "expunge_deletes_allowed": "10.0",
                        "segments_per_tier": "10.0",
                        "deletes_pct_allowed": "33.0"
                    }
                },
                "max_refresh_listeners": "1000",
                "max_regex_length": "1000",
                "load_fixed_bitset_filters_eagerly": "true",
                "number_of_routing_shards": "5",
                "write": {
                    "wait_for_active_shards": "1"
                },
                "mapping": {
                    "coerce": "false",
                    "nested_fields": {
                        "limit": "50"
                    },
                    "depth": {
                        "limit": "20"
                    },
                    "ignore_malformed": "false",
                    "total_fields": {
                        "limit": "1000"
                    }
                },
                "source_only": "false",
                "soft_deletes": {
                    "enabled": "false",
                    "retention": {
                        "operations": "0"
                    }
                },
                "max_script_fields": "32",
                "query": {
                    "default_field": [
                        "*"
                    ],
                    "parse": {
                        "allow_unmapped_fields": "true"
                    }
                },
                "format": "0",
                "frozen": "false",
                "sort": {
                    "missing": [],
                    "mode": [],
                    "field": [],
                    "order": []
                },
                "priority": "1",
                "codec": "default",
                "max_rescore_window": "10000",
                "max_adjacency_matrix_filters": "100",
                "gc_deletes": "60s",
                "optimize_auto_generated_id": "true",
                "max_ngram_diff": "1",
                "translog": {
                    "generation_threshold_size": "64mb",
                    "flush_threshold_size": "512mb",
                    "sync_interval": "5s",
                    "retention": {
                        "size": "512mb",
                        "age": "12h"
                    },
                    "durability": "REQUEST"
                },
                "auto_expand_replicas": "false",
                "mapper": {
                    "dynamic": "true"
                },
                "requests": {
                    "cache": {
                        "enable": "true"
                    }
                },
                "data_path": "",
                "highlight": {
                    "max_analyzed_offset": "-1"
                },
                "routing": {
                    "rebalance": {
                        "enable": "all"
                    },
                    "allocation": {
                        "enable": "all",
                        "total_shards_per_node": "-1"
                    }
                },
                "search": {
                    "slowlog": {
                        "level": "TRACE",
                        "threshold": {
                            "fetch": {
                                "warn": "-1",
                                "trace": "-1",
                                "debug": "-1",
                                "info": "-1"
                            },
                            "query": {
                                "warn": "-1",
                                "trace": "-1",
                                "debug": "-1",
                                "info": "-1"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "throttled": "false"
                },
                "fielddata": {
                    "cache": "node"
                },
                "default_pipeline": "_none",
                "max_slices_per_scroll": "1024",
                "shard": {
                    "check_on_startup": "false"
                },
                "xpack": {
                    "watcher": {
                        "template": {
                            "version": ""
                        }
                    },
                    "version": "",
                    "ccr": {
                        "following_index": "false"
                    }
                },
                "percolator": {
                    "map_unmapped_fields_as_text": "false",
                    "map_unmapped_fields_as_string": "false"
                },
                "allocation": {
                    "max_retries": "5"
                },
                "refresh_interval": "1s",
                "indexing": {
                    "slowlog": {
                        "reformat": "true",
                        "threshold": {
                            "index": {
                                "warn": "-1",
                                "trace": "-1",
                                "debug": "-1",
                                "info": "-1"
                            }
                        },
                        "source": "1000",
                        "level": "TRACE"
                    }
                },
                "compound_format": "0.1",
                "blocks": {
                    "metadata": "false",
                    "read": "false",
                    "read_only_allow_delete": "false",
                    "read_only": "false",
                    "write": "false"
                },
                "max_result_window": "10000",
                "store": {
                    "stats_refresh_interval": "10s",
                    "type": "",
                    "fs": {
                        "fs_lock": "native"
                    },
                    "preload": []
                },
                "queries": {
                    "cache": {
                        "enabled": "true"
                    }
                },
                "ttl": {
                    "disable_purge": "false"
                },
                "warmer": {
                    "enabled": "true"
                },
                "max_shingle_diff": "3",
                "query_string": {
                    "lenient": "false"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any hint?
Thanks

Comment: That's an interesting problem. If you run `GET _cat/indices?v` before and after the indexing operations, do you see any differences?

Comment: Hello Val, thank you for your reply, unfortunately i had to restart service to unlock customer so i can't provide details, anyway, for sure document count is not growing. Have you ever observed any similar behavior?

Comment: Can you make sure to run this the next time it happens (in a few days)? Do you have any automated process running that might change the index setting in the background? Can you GET the index _settings the next time that happens?

Comment: This is what i get from _settings, i've done this the last time it was hanged    
     "settings": {
            "index": {
                "creation_date": "1628763148510",
                "number_of_shards": "5",
                "number_of_replicas": "1",
                "uuid": "2yfLQd4MSSuSpEt1UNaxSg",
                "version": {
                    "created": "6060299"
                },
                "provided_name": "xxx"
            }
        }

Comment: Thanks, but it would be interesting to see the settings the next time this issue happens.

Comment: Hello @Val, i updated question with output from _settings API